# Can you track when Sonar first identified a code smell?

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

I started working in a new code base. A few days later, SonarQube had an update and our technical debt doubled.

I suspect this is due to false positive code smells. The issue is, I can't tell  which ones are newly identified; the "creation date" field seems to only filter by when the code was first introduced.